# Deshabilitar un checkbox dependiendo del texto

Tags: javascript

Tengo una tabla en la cual contiene varios datos, uno de ellos es un checkbox, y en la misma fila uno de los datos dice "sin tickets disponibles". Lo que quiero hacer es que los inputs que tengan esa leyenda en la fila, estén deshabilitados. Y los que digan "Autorizados" se puedan presionar el check.

Si pudiera solicitar una guía de cómo hacerlo, os agradeceré mucho!
Esta es mi Tabla, está en un while

```
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="id-datos" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row[6] ?>">
            <?php if ($row[7] == 1): ?>
            <input class="habilitar task-chk" name="habilitar" type="checkbox" checked >
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php if($row[7] == 0): ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk" name="habilitar">
            <?php endif;?>
            </td>
            <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
            <td><?=str_ireplace($serv_regular, $serv_nueva, $row[3])?></td>
            <td class="datos-td"><?=str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[4])?></td>
            <td><?=$row[5];?></td>
    </tr>
```

El row[4] es el campo que dice Autorizado y Sin ticket disponibles dependiendo del valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que agregar una validación en tus checkbox de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php if($row[7] == 0): ?>
<?php if ($row[4] == "Sin tickets disponibles"): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk" name="habilitar" disabled>
<?php else: ?>
    <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk" name="habilitar">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Gracias! funciono perfecto.